# Get template if on the same page in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have made a SPA where I used Angular `ui-router`.

My tester is giving me bug that if I am on the same template and navigating on the same page by clicking header menu, it happens nothing.

Can I reload template again still if I am already on that template?

Comment: It is not a bug. You shoud disable the link. There is no meaning to click on same link which you are already in.

Comment: If user need to reload. They should clik on reload.  Making to happy tester if you do it, then it will be a poor user experience.  Make it seledted and dusabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
<a ui-sref="myState({foo: bar})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">new post</a>
```